how to add a expandable option to the windows context menu in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
i am trying to make an option in the context menu something like this
image
so that when you hover over it it has multiple options.
i tryed searching on google but only thing that comes up is how to add a single option not an expandible one.
i tryed putting it like this
image
but it just puts a single non expandible one

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Using Windows registry you can only add a top-level menu item. The WinRAR example you included in your post uses a dll file that is registered in Registry. When the expandable submenu is about to be shown the code from within that dll defines what entries should be shown and what happens when they are clicked.
